# Inconsistency for decreasing loss

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, data-science

- [x] Check that you are up-to-date with the master branch of Keras. You can update with:
  pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade --no-deps
- [x] If running on TensorFlow, check that you are up-to-date with the latest version. The installation instructions can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup).
- [x] Provide a link to a GitHub Gist of a Python script that can reproduce your issue (or just copy the script here if it is short).

Hello everyone, I have been using this script [Python script](https://github.com/etai83/lstm_stock_prediction/blob/master/.ipynb_checkpoints/GOOGLE%20stock%20prediction-checkpoint.ipynb) 
The problem is that I am unable to produce similar result everytime. 
Sometimes, I can produce a similar result (loss of 0.3~ within 500 epochs) but sometimes I still get a loss of 3.x after 1500epochs. I am not sure if this is a bug or this is because the algorithm just stuck at a local minimum .

Moreover, after I adjusted the close price (without dividing by 100) and I increased the learning rate for 100x, the problem still exists and it stuck at a loss of 30000. Do you guys think there is anything can do to improve the model?

Comment: did you try different optimizers? Sometimes lstms work much better with Adam or Adadelta instead of RMSPROP.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I was using Adam and I'm trying to use Adadelta now. Let me update it to you later.

Comment: also btw, in the meantime since the notebook was released there is a new keras and tensorflow major release, so using the latest release or master branches might not be the correct way to reproduce.

Comment: By using a model without the relu layer and Adam optimizer, it can achieve a low loss for the dataset that has been divided by 100. 

But using it to train a dataset that has not been divided by 100, it still stuck. 

I have tried to increase the number of neuron to 1024 in the first LSTM layer but the problem still exists.

Comment: good news, you might want to standardize the data beforehand, so it has 0 mean and unit variance.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, after normalizing it, it wokrs fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By normalizing the featureset, it works fine now.